# Can we reduce the android App size in uno platform?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uno-platform

I noticed that on release configuration an Uno blank app is about 22mb for android. Can it be reduced ..?
I also noticed that a blank xamarin forms app is only 14 mb. (Both for per abi apk)

Answer (score 3):

You can enable Application App bundles (.aab). It will reduce your application size even more once deployed through the Google Play store.

To enable it, look in your *.Droid.csproj properties

[image: csproj options]

This [xamarin blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/) is a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can do to reduce the app size.

#### Enable Android App Bundle (.aab)

If you currently use the .apk format for your Android package, you can reduce your app size by switching to .aab format.

[Here is a guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/android-app-bundle/) on how to enable it.

#### Enable Profiled-AOT

If you currently use full AOT, you can reduce the app size by enabling Profiled-AOT.

[Here is a guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/faster-android-startup-times-with-startup-tracing/) on how to enable it.

#### Remove unused assets

Make sure you remove any asset that you don't actually use in your app. That includes images, fonts, sounds, videos, etc.

#### Remove unused package references

Make sure you remove nuget references that you don't actually use.